# heroku nodejs dependencies synthax

Tags: node.js, heroku, dependencies

Which is the syntax to specify a module dependency on any (or last) version ?

I know that for a specific one, the synthax is :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.9.8"
  },
```

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "on any (or last) version"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While installing you can install with
`npm install express` for the latest version.

If you want a specific version.
You can install with `npm install express@4.9.8`

Comment: Yes, but I want that Heroku pipeline install the latest, without specifying a precise one. So I need the syntax for Heroku.

Comment: There is no "syntax for Heroku". There's syntax for a _`package.json` file_, though.

Comment: It is not recommended to update the latest version each time. The package version you are using at the time of development; you should use that . If you need to update each package you should again test your entire project . It may fails somewhere and you have to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
The answer from Chris seems to be the good one : from "https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning" :

```
"You can specify which update types your package can accept from dependencies in your package's package.json file.
For example, to specify acceptable version ranges up to 1.0.4, use the following syntax:
Patch releases: 1.0 or 1.0.x or ~1.0.4
Minor releases: 1 or 1.x or ^1.0.4
Major releases: * or x"
```